# Correlation for one image pixels

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I want to calculate the correlation coefficient for my image pixel(binary)and after that for my encrypted image. I know `corr2` is for calculating the correlation coefficient for two images.

But is there a function for calculating the correlation coefficient for one image in matlab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

under matlab ?
you can use ifft ( fft ( image1 ) x  fft ( image2 ) ) ... it will return the 2D correlation matrix and Locate the maximum peak !!!!

Good luck

Comment: Actually I want a number not a matrix.for real image  it should be about 1 and for encrypted image  about 0.

Comment: Add a look at the matlab corr2 function description ... It's a bit complex to compute ... You should but the complexity of my proposal on real image should be lower...,,